# How to count one factor on basis of another factor

Tags: r

```
Days   Sentiment
Mon     Positive
Tues    Negative
Wed     Positive
Thurs   Negative
Friday  Positive
Sat     Negative
Sun     Positive
Mon     Positive
Tues    Negative
Wed     Positive
Thurs   Negative
Friday  Positive
Sat     Negative
Sun     Positive
```

Using above data I want to create new data frame like given below. It will count days as unique value and count number of positive or negative sentiments present in it.

```
Days       Positive     Negative
Mon         2              0
Tuesday     0              2
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: You can do: `xtabs(~ Days + Sentiment, data = df)`. Or even: `table(df)`.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare Data

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

data <- data.frame(Days = rep(weekdays(seq(today(),(today() + days(6)), by = "day")),2),
                   Sentiment = sample(c("Positive","Negative"),14,replace = TRUE),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Use `dplyr` and `reshpae2`

```
data %>%
    group_by(Days, Sentiment) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    dcast(Days ~ Sentiment, value = count) %>%
    mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.),0,.))
```

```
       Days Negative Positive
1    Friday        2        0
2    Monday        1        1
3  Saturday        1        1
4    Sunday        0        2
5  Thursday        0        2
6   Tuesday        2        0
7 Wednesday        1        1
```